# Why doesn't strcpy fail here? Deliberate

Tags: c

Why don't I get a segmentation fault or something?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char msg[5];
    strcpy(msg, "dsasgagasagfggdag");

}
```

Comment: See [A Guide to Undefined Behavior](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213). It's also important to understand, in this case, that the `strcpy` function does not know the maximum length of `msg` (nor is `msg` capable of resizing as needed) so it cannot prevent the buffer overflow from happening. Whether or not that overflow causes a seg fault falls into the province of 'undefined behavior'.

Comment: If you really want to stress test it, try strcpy with a few MiB of data.  I can certainly see a reasonable implementation giving your stack variable 32 or 64 or 512 bytes, in which case writing 18 bytes is not going to overflow anything.

Comment: I started writing an answer, then I realized I couldn't be precise enough. So I write here. A segmentation fault occurs when memory area outside the _segment_ assigned to the current process is accessed. The **stack area** belongs to the process from its "birth", and your 5 bytes `msg` array is on top of it. Writing data to `msg` will eventually lead to segmentation fault, but the number of out of bound written bytes required to make the system crash may vary with OS, the "direction" of the stack (topdown vs bottomup) and with other several params. That's why it is called undefined behavior...

Comment: @WilliamPursell stack overflow is not what happens. Stacks are usually filled from the top address and the stack pointer is decreased whenever a local is allocated or a function is called. SO occurs when the base address of the stack (in this upside-down logic) is reached. In our case msg is on top of the stack (but at the lowest address..) before `strcpy` is called. Going out of bounds first some padding is overwritten  (if 4-bytes aligned), then `argc` / `argv` (that are there even if not present in main call) and then some OS dependant consolle environment data...

Comment: ... after the latter data the bigger address of the stack (that represents the base of the stack...) is reached and probably there segfault occurs. I'm not sure about the amount of this _OS dependant data_, and that's what prevented me to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you allocate a block of memory in C, it **usually** tries to return you a block of consecutive addresses, for example, for msg[5], let's say the first address of a byte is 42, then the next address is going to be 43, the next, 44, then 45 and 46. So, following this idea, if the address 47 is free (if it's not allocated by another variable) it's gonna store the next byte of the string (for "dsasgagasagfggdag", it would store the character 'a').

Therefore, this behavior only occur due to causality. The right way to do it would be to use the function 'malloc' with the exact amount of characters, so you could be sure that you have all your chars stored in the right adresses.

Comment: When you say it "usually" tries to return you a block of consecutive addresses, is there a scenario where it would not (other than out of heap when it would return NULL)?

Comment: Thank you.  So, the overflow is not guaranteed!   Tricky!

Comment: @JackOfAll it is not an overflow in its classic meaning. See comments section for my explanation. Also, using  `malloc` doesn't prevent the segfault; it just makes it happen in a more deterministic way, as the addresses contiguous to the allocated ones are illegal (unlike in the stack). Allocating enough space for the string is the solution for both dynamic and static memory.

Comment: @JackOfAll -- it doesn't _have_ to be tricky. Most C compilers can generate stack-smashing detection code, which will detect even small overflows, at the expense of adding a few clock cycles to each function call.